# Intellij Idea sometimes doesn't build the application the way it supposed to

Tags: java, intellij-idea, build

I'm building a node editor application. I've a class that extends as a JFrame. And it's filled with a JPanel. I've set its background color to black. And also I've assigned it a JPopupMenu.
After a successful build,

*At the first build the JFrame just appears as a dull JFrame with nothing.         also there's no any PopupMenu.
*Second time also same. Nothing but a dull frame.
*Sometimes 3rd time it comes in the way it supposed to. Black and with a PopupMenu. But occasionally this time also it comes dull.
*Fortunately I hadn't got wrong build more than three times yet. Fourth time it appears fine.

I'm using Ubuntu 18.04 operating system. Using Intellij Idea with JDK10. I can't really figure out what's wrong. Can some one help me with this? Here is my GUI class,

```
package Framework;

import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.geom.Point2D;

class GUI extends JFrame {
    private JPopupMenu defaultPopup = new JPopupMenu();
    private Canvas defaultCanvas = new Canvas(defaultPopup);

void Create() throws Exception{
    this.setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    this.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    this.setSize(new Dimension(500,600));
    this.setTitle("Framework : Node Editor");
    this.setVisible(true);
    BuildClickMenu();
    this.add(defaultCanvas);
}

private void addNode(Node node, Point2D location){
    defaultCanvas.nodes.add(node.Create(location));
}

private void BuildClickMenu() throws Exception{
    int chainLength = 0;
    JMenu extender = new JMenu("Extender");
    ...
}
    }
```

I've shortened the code to make it simple. Popup code is in the Canvas class. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Please edit the title to be more specific

Comment: Could be Linux issue, see https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Java#Non-reparenting_window_managers.